# What kind of wood was the standard decking for aircraft carriers in World War 2?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, japan, naval, construction

I know that both Japan and the United States used wooden decks on their WWII Aircraft Carriers. Was there a specific, "ideal" standard type of wood that was utilized by either country? If so, what kind of wood was deemed the best for the job?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out it was teak wood.

> Teak was the preferred would and the red brown color wouldn't be a mahogony stain, but the natural color. As teak is sourced from the Thai/Burma area, Dec. 7th ended the supply chain. Douglas-Fir was substituted on the newer carriers in WWII, and that would have to have been stained and subsequently painted. *[finescale.com](http://cs.finescale.com/fsm/modeling_subjects/f/7/t/132172.aspx)*

Comment: Using Douglas fir, which is less dense than teak, would also have a positive effect on ship stability (CG would be lowered slightly lower due to less weight high on the ship).

Answer (score -1):

Douglas fir with Oregon pine borders.
Teak was only used on battleships and cruisers
As even with the supply chain active there wasn't enough Teak.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).